# AM437x/AM335x Audio clock generation

Tags: arm, clock, texas-instruments

For some ADCs and DACs I'm using I need a 24.576MHz clock (96kHz * 256). Obviously I can use a low jitter audio clock generator. However, I have a AM335x processor available that claims to have a low jitter clock (ADPLLJ). Could I use this clock? It appears that it can be divided and multiplied to reach that frequency and it would save some trouble of getting a clock generator and a crystal oscillator if I could use this low jitter clock. The clock is explained in the AM437x reference manual. The clock also exists on the AM335x but the reference manual only mentions it briefly.

[AM437x](http://www.ti.com/lit/ug/spruhl7d/spruhl7d.pdf)
[AM335x](http://www.ti.com/lit/ug/spruh73m/spruh73m.pdf)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, it seems you can't.

I guess you'll use McASP0 or McASP1 to drive the DAC/ADC. Their clock is derived from either CLK_M_OSC (the oscillator output, so no PLL) or CORE_CLKOUTM4/2 aka L3S_CLK (see page 4549, also confirmed by table Table 8-23 page 1143). This clock is itself derived from ADPLLS (see page 1141), not ADPLLLJ. ADPLLLJ feeds some other perpherals (see page 1144).

Comment: I see, thanks for the help! @dim I am using McASP0 as a SPDIF audio transmitter and receiver. But I can use the McASP1 clock for sure. However I have another question. I have a somewhat large number of ADCs and DACs. I'm using the PCM4201 and PCM4202 ADCs, and the PCM1789 and PCM1690 DACs. They all use a audio serial port protocol made by texas instruments. Could I configure the GPIO of the AM355x to transmit and receive this data?

Comment: I think transmiting serial data over gpio is very impractical. This may even be impossible if the frequency is too high, and anyway, it will slow down the proc a lot. However, the am33x has PRUs that you can maybe configure to do that. I don't know much about them however.

Comment: Yeah, I think the best solution is to use an FPGA to interface with the data converters and interface the FPGA with the processor.

Comment: If you have lots and lots of DAC/ADC, yes, but honestly, have a look at the PRUs, I seem to remember they were designed for this kind of cases, so it might be enough for your needs.

Comment: I'll look into that. They have enough pins for sure.